# Converting AM/PM time to standard time format hh:mm in C#

Tags: c#, time

In my ASP.NET web form I have 3 fields - hour, minute and am/pm drop down. How can I get the values of those 3 fields into one variable and then convert the am/pm hour to standard 24 hour time like 05:20PM = 17:20. This needs to be done in C#.

Thanks for the help beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying your starting out with separate values for hour, minute, and am/pm?

```
    public string Get24HourTime(int hour, int minute, string ToD)
    {           
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        if (ToD.ToUpper() == "PM") hour = (hour  % 12) + 12;

        return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).ToString("HH:mm");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The user will put separate values for hour minute and am/pm.

Comment: The code doesn't work. It says that DateTime can't accept 5 parameters.

Comment: I guess thats what I get for not testing my code. DateTime needed a parameter for seconds. I just used 0, but I suppose its really up to you.

Comment: If the time is 12:xx AM, adding 12 to the hour will result in an invalid hour value 24. The DateTime constructor MAY modulo it, but the more correct method would be to add, then modulo (or vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

```
var hour = int.Parse(ddlHour.SelectedValue);
var min = int.Parse(ddlMin.SelectedValue);
var ampm = ddlAmPm.SelectedValue;

hour = ampm == "AM" ? hour : (hour % 12) + 12; //convert 12-hour time to 24-hour

var dateTime = new DateTime(0,0,0, hour, min, 0);
var timeString = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: unnecessary reassignment in 50% of the cases, use: if (ampm == "PM") hour = (hour % 12) + 12;  still does the job +1

Comment: Very true. I'd originally inlined that code into the DateTime constructor parameter, which would have preserved the original hour value, but looked too busy.

Answer (score 1):

You can put dummy year, month and day if only time is needed.

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
string time = time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: The time is a user input value.

Answer (score 1):

```
string hour = hourField.Text
string minute = minuteField.Text

string AMPM = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();

//AMPM is either "AM" or "PM"
timeString = hour + ":" + minute + " " + AMPM

//the procued string in timeString is e.g. "10:45 PM"
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(timeString);
```

You have to observe that 12:00AM is midnight and should produce 00:00. The fact that 12:00AM is one hour before 1:00AM, using modulo you would have to do it like:

```
if(hour == 12)hour = 0;
if(AMPM == "PM") hour = (hour % 12) + 12;
```